# syntax error executing regex on bash

Tags: regex, bash, terminal

I have the following small code to retrieve file name,

```
    for pfile in ../data/${BENCH}/*.data; do
        prot=`expr match ${pfile%.data} "../data/${BENCH}/\(.*\)"`
        echo ${prot}
    done
```

pfile%.data is a string like "../data/gpcr/3.4.5.data". However this expression returns 'syntax error'.

I also tried,

```
prot=`expr match "${pfile%.data}" "../data/${BENCH}/\(.*\)"`   AND
prot=`expr match "${pfile%.data}" : "../data/${BENCH}/\(.*\)"` AND
prot=`expr match "${pfile%.data}" '../data/${BENCH}/\(.*\)'`
```

neither of them worked. I am running these on MacOSX terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `expr match "${pfile%.data}" "../data/${BENCH}/\(.*\)"` suppose to do?

Comment: It is supposed to retrieve "3.4.5" part of the pfile%.data which is  "../data/gpcr/3.4.5.data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expr.1.html, you need to drop the "match" keyword, which does not exist in this implementation

```
prot=$(expr ${pfile%.data} : "../data/${BENCH}/\(.*\)")
```

But since you have bash:

```
prot=${pfile%.data}
prot=${prot##*/}
echo "$prot"
```

Or you could do:

```
prot=$( basename "$pfile" ".data" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Would just this work for you?

```
for pfile in ../data/$BENCH/*.data; do
    [[ $pfile =~ ^../data/$BENCH/(.*).data$ ]]
    prot=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "$prot"
done
```

(I guess it's what you're trying to express with the `expr match` statement).